# Bootstrap how to break table columns into new rows when screen is small

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table like so

```
            <table id="tblFilters" dir="rtl" class="table">
          <thead class="filterHead">
            <tr class="filterRow">
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="filterBody">

            <tr class="filterRow">
              <td>
                <span>הצג מתאריך</span>
                <input type="text" id="dateFrom" />
              </td>
              <td>
                 <span>עד לתאריך</span>
                <input type="text" id="dateTo" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <span>שם לקוח\מספר IQC</span>
                <input type="text" id="iqcNo" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <asp:Button  style="float:left; margin-right:30px;" id="btnRefreshReport" OnClientClick="refreshReport()" runat="server" Text="רענן דוח"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

I want each of the inputs (with its text) to align its own row when the screen is small (xs/sm) and when the screen is bigger they will all be in the same row.

how can I do this using bootstrap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use media queries and set the all the cells to block to make them break

**See example bellow:**

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .table>tbody>tr>td,
  .table>tbody>tr>th,
  .table>tfoot>tr>td,
  .table>tfoot>tr>th,
  .table>thead>tr>td,
  .table>thead>tr>th {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%!important;
  }
  .table>thead>tr>th {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .table .filterBody span {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="tblFilters" dir="rtl" class="table">
  <thead class="filterHead">
    <tr class="filterRow">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="filterBody">

    <tr class="filterRow">
      <td>
        <span>הצג מתאריך</span>
        <input type="text" id="dateFrom" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>עד לתאריך</span>
        <input type="text" id="dateTo" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>שם לקוח\מספר IQC</span>
        <input type="text" id="iqcNo" />
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks man! it does the trick, if you don't mind, I would also like the rows in the small screen size to be aligned one below the other. I changed the table in my example so the text and the inputs are in the same cell, and when the cells break into new rows they are not aligned correctly one below the other, is there a way of doing that?

Comment: @itay312 you can do the same thing with spans, make them a block element on small screens, see my edit

Comment: Oh I see, Thanks! you have been very helpful